# Openbox login black screen with no gui in lubuntu 16.04?

Tags: lubuntu, gui, lxde, openbox

I dont remember what i did but after restart and logging in only black screen is shown with cursor. When i right click a menu appears Terminal Emulator and some other basic options. Openbox is running but no panel no nothing, but i am able to run apps through terminal, can somebody help me fix this? I am using lubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click in the middle and select **Exit**.